# Android DDMS Cannot start network statistics with emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms, android-sdk-tools

As soon as the start button is clicked, Error dialog is shown.

Problem reading stats

Reason:
Problem reading xt_qtaguid network statistics from selected device.

I am testing with newest 4.2.2 emulator.  (I've read about network stats not being supported before 4.0.1)

PATH variables in OS = OK
can run ADB from cmd line
All other DDMS functions are working.
Running newest Eclipse as of 3-31-2013.